# gdal.Warp - set env var

Tags: gdalwarp, ubuntu, python-3, anaconda, amazon-ec2

I set up an ubuntu 18.04 EC2 through AWS that "On Start" will run a python script in which will download a `.tif` from an s3 bucket and project it from `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:3857` using `gdal.Warp()`. The method to execute the script on start was used from this [question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955604/start-a-python-script-at-boot-on-ubuntu). I am also using an anaconda3 env to host the script and desired packages. GDAL was installed with `conda install -c conda-forge gdal=3.0.2`.

**onStartUp.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Some kind of description

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/bin/python3.8 /home/ubuntu/run.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can successfully project with the code below both through my local machine and with the EC2 if executed with `python myScript.py`, however when used in conjunction with the "On Start" method, I receive an error.

I [found](https://github.com/developmentseed/sentinel-util/issues/2) that this is due to the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable being not properly set for a server use case. I am not entirely sure how to set this variable, weather I need to set it in the main script or in the command terminal. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444310/how-to-set-the-gdal-data-environment-variable-to-point-to-the-directory-containi), and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883445/how-to-fix-the-enviroment-variable-gdal-data-path-set), but they were unsuccessful.

```
from osgeo import gdal

def reproject(output_raster, filename):
    input_raster = gdal.Open(filename)
    warp_options = gdal.WarpOptions(creationOptions = ['COMPRESS=DEFLATE', 'PREDICTOR=2', 'ZLEVEL=9'], srcSRS='EPSG:4326', dstSRS='EPSG:3857', resampleAlg='near', format='GTiff')
    warp = gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, options=warp_options)
    warp = None

warp = gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, options=warp_options)
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 625, in Warp
return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 3410, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName
return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'
```

**Updates**
I was able to find some more information running `journalctl -xe`

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/share/proj failed
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
EPSG:4326
```

Comment: try adding this environment variable `PROJ_LIB=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/share/proj`.  Also try upgrading your gdal to a different (later) version

Comment: @AmanBagrecha thanks! I actually just found a [similar response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472933/pyinstaller-executable-fails) from a 'stackoverflow' post. Unforturantly I cannot Flag the question as a duplicate since they are two different sites.

Comment: If it solves the error, the mods can take the call. But did that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes is did solve the issue. I just flagged it for the mods.

Comment: @AmanBagrecha Flag was declined. If you want to post, I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following environment variable

```shell
PROJ_LIB=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/share/proj
```

Where the path is pointing to `proj` directory inside your conda environment

Comment: I'd like to add that if you activate the environment, I do not need to set the `PROJ_LIB` var. But if I run the script via `onStartUp.service` then the `PROJ_LIB` var does need to be set.